# mongoose pull specific data from single document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So Im using mongoose and mongo atlas. I have a single document with a structure as follows:

```
{_id: ObjectId("3u3ui4t432) ,
name: cat1,
items : 
    [
    {cat1_item1: "something"},
    {cat1_item2: "something"}
   ]}

{_id: ObjectId("3u3uir3bi2) ,
name: cat2,
items : 
    [
    {cat2_item1: "something"},
    {cat2_item2: "something"}
   ]}
```

currently this endpoint retrieves the entire document, i am just trying to access one category at a time based of a param either url or body

```
//this gets the specific document i want, but i would prefer to get that document through something like this.
// findOne({ category: req.body.category })
app.post('/targetCategory', async (req, res) => {
    const categoryName = req.body.category
    categoryCollection.findOne({ _id: "62b9353730ac42a7d390f5ad" }, (err, 
data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send(data)
            console.log(categoryName)
        }
    })
})
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = Schema({
    categories: {

    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('categoryCollection', categorySchema)
```

basically I want to use params(?) to only access one category at a time to minimise data sent to the frontend. How do i go about using something like findOne() with the param being either category1 or category2 as I only want the array inside. I am using mongoose, node and express.

Comment: I am trying to understand. Find methods brings the whole collection in an array as a single member but your code suggests findOne will bring the whole collection too, only not in an array. if you have only one categories document in the collection why not turn it into a model and make each category a document with fields of categoryName and items array.
Otherwise you will have to fetch whole collection from database and eliminate unneeded part manually, unneccessary expense on database and server.

Comment: thats pretty much what i am trying to avoid, i assumed findOne selected the document then maybe another method to only pull the data i want? if need be, i will make each category a document if thats the only way to handle this. if i didnt care about the load on the server/db id just send the whole lot to the front end to deal with lmao

Comment: I will make a design in the way I think you want. Lets see :)

Comment: thought that through and yeah that makes a ton of sense actually. so how would i handle the findone() through use of a category name param?

Comment: The collection's `findOne` method retrieves only one matching document if there is a match (else a `null` or `undefined`). And, its a convention to use a GET method to send query criteria and retrieve result data in the response (POST is not used for this purpose).

Answer (score 0):

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    // items placeholder, modify if required
    items: String[]
})

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema)
module.exports = Category
```

the controller you can use

```
app.post('/listOne', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const categoryData = await Category.findOne({name: req.body.category})
    res.send({category: categoryData})
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

another controller solution I suggest

```
app.get('/category/:name', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const categoryData = await Category.findOne({name: req.params.name})
    res.send({category: categoryData})
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

Comment: using the first solution, im still getting the first document regardless of what body param, if any i use

Comment: that is expected. mongoose doesn't automatically arrange your documents to fit the new design. It's up to you to reinsert the data or implement other ugly and expensive solution.
What do you mean first document? we did this design because your collection consists of only one giant document?

Comment: ohhh I took your advice and made each category a document in the collection, sorry for that confusion

Comment: I thought findOne targets a single document out of many inside a collection?

Comment: yes that's right. but the question unanswered is, are there more than one document in your collection?

Comment: there is now yeah, one for each category (only two at the moment for working on this will be adding more once it works)

Comment: and im trying to target one of the documents using the 'name' field. ```findOne({name: req.body.name})``` but it still returns the first document, i am able to console log and res.send() the req.body.name data so its not undefined either

Comment: so problem solved? I can help either way. Just accurately describe the problem LOL :)

Comment: i know haha im sorry this got out of hand real fast. im just trying to get a specific document based of a field in that document, called name which is beneath the _id.  but it keeps returning the first document. so not really working. It seems i can force the result i want by directly inserting the id of the document i want into the findOne() query but thats not really practical

Comment: ill show you via edit

Comment: as shown in the edit using the ID gets me the document I want but i cant seem to make it work with body data. it still only returns the first category regardless of method criteria

Comment: do you have ref types inside your categories?. No offense but you still didn't provide enough information about the shape of your data. actually I am not sure if you use the word "document" correctly in the context of mongodb

Comment: i got it working, and yeah i wasnt super helpful i know sorry about all that, you helped me fix it though! shockingly enough I have used mongoDB alot in the past but only now am i trying to be very considerate of the load on the server and db as im trying to write more healthy code so yeah the termination gets pretty iffy on my behalf. thanks for you help dude <3

Answer (score 0):

To find single data in collection you can use this function or read this in mongoose docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

```
// Find one adventure whose `country` is 'Croatia', otherwise `null`
await Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }).exec();

// using callback
Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, function (err, adventure) {});

// select only the adventures name and length
await Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }, 'name length').exec();
```

and to get parameter in express you can use this

```
app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params)
})
```